# Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "The filter image lazy load" plugin does not exist

Tags: drush, 10

How can I resolve this issue? This log issue occurs in Drupal 10.0.10, Drush 12.2.0 PHP 8.1
Everything seemed fine when I had upgraded to D10 all the sites were working fine, All of sudden its starting to throw this error when I had cleared cache.

I tried resolving it deleting the vendor and composer lock and then running a composer update it did not work.

I am assuming the issue is caused by Blazy module. I hope I am correct. I tried to remove the module and but its dependency modules are failing to delete.

```
0-php-errors.log                                                                     
Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Class "\Drupal\text\Plugin\Field\FieldType\TextFieldItemList" not found" at /mnt/www/html/Development/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/TypedData/TypedDataManager.php line 91 request_id="v-82976780-5dd8-11ee-8de8-b7f4d9badddd"
 Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "filter_image_lazy_load" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\filter\FilterPluginManager are: blazy_filter, editor_file_reference, entity_embed, filter_align, filter_autop, filter_caption, filter_html, filter_htmlcorrector, filter_html_escape, filter_html_image_secure, filter_null, filter_url, media_embed, filter_responsive_tables_filter, slick_filter, video_embed_wysiwyg" at /mnt/www/html/Development/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 53 request_id="v-2aa6af7a-5dda-11ee-a334-e7cbdc62d936"
```

Comment: Obtain stack traces. Add them to the Question. This question is rather vague as it is currently written.

Comment: Also, what is unclear about the error message, the `filter_image_lazy_load` plugin is missing, those plugins are usually configured and should be easily found in a config export? You can either remove it from the config or install a module providing the filter plugin.

Comment: @4uk4 could you please suggest me how can I do this  "You can either remove it from the config or install a module providing the filter plugin"  I have never do this before?

Comment: Goto */admin/config/development/configuration/full/export*, download the full configuration, then search for the machine name of the missing filter. You can also search in the code of modules you had installed to find the module providing this filter.

Comment: The odd thing, this filter is a D10 core filter installed by default.

Comment: I am unable to login to the backend of the site

Comment: Does `drush cedit filter.format.full_html` work? Then you can remove the filter from all text formats like full_html, basic_html ...

Comment: Did you forget to run `composer install`? You might have the wrong version of Drupal installed and you're trying to import D10 config into a D9 site.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue rolling back from Drupal 10.1.4 to 9.5.11. You can get the conflicting config with this cmd  `drush cget filter.format.basic_html filters.filter_image_lazy_load`
then you will be able to remove from DB with  `drush cdel filter.format.basic_html filters.filter_image_lazy_load`

Comment: This worked, thanks.